# Global filter in a single sheet

Tags: tableau-api

Recently, I saw a tableau workbook with all filters in one dashboard. Simply it acts as a master filter for all the dashboards. How to create such a dashboard with global filter alone in one place without any graphs?

Comment: Create a filter and apply for all worksheets

Comment: Yes, but my requirment is I need filters alone in one sheet without any charts. So that it acts a standaolone filter sheet for all the sheets.

Comment: exactly first apply for all sheets and then create a dashboard with the same filter which will work for all sheets in dashboard

Answer (score 1):

On any of the worksheets you have on the dashboard, click the Options button. In the dropdown menu, one option will say Filter. That opens a submenu of all possible filter dimensions and measures. Choose one and it will create the filter on the dashboard itself. And as @Silva said, make sure to set it to Apply to All Worksheets.

1. Click on the sheet in the dashboard
2. In the upper right of the layout container, there is an arrow, a funnel, and a "x".

   3. Select the arrow.
   4. Hover over Filters.
   5. Select which filter should be added to the dashboard.

Video from Tableau available at http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/adding-filters-to-dashboards.